# How do I restore rsync backup files with the correct owner on a new machine?

Tags: linux, backup, permissions, rsync, file-permissions

I have backed up my home folder to an external (ext4) hard drive, preserving ownership and permissions. Now I want to do a fresh Linux install and then restore my home folder from the backup. But the ownership is just a UID number, and when I plug the drive into a different machine as a test, I see that the UID is associated with a different, incorrect user name on this machine. Is there a way to tell rsync to translate the UIDs on the backup files to the correct UIDs on the new machine when it restores the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rsync has two options to map userids and groupids during the copy. For example,

```
-o -g --usermap=1000:abc,1001:def --groupmap=1000:abc,1001:def
```

will convert user and group id 1000 in the backup to the name `abc` in the copy, and similarly 1001 to `def`. The `-o -g` options are included by `-a`, so you often won't need them explicitly.